# Find eigenvalues of a general matrix - Decomosition or generalized eigenvalue problem?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

I have a general matrix $A$. Not symmetric, it's just random with real numbers. 
I want to find eigenvalues and eigenvectors from it. How can I do that?

I have tried QR-Algorithm. But that requries $A$ to be symmetrical or vandermode.

Should I try to solve $det(A-\lambda I)=0$ instead, even if $A$ is really big?

Comment: @Moo Code please. But first I need to have an algorithm to start with. That algorithm should be math-stuffs.

Comment: @Moo That's  containing QR-algorithm. Does not work with non-symmetrical matrices.

Comment: @Moo That's OK! If I use Hessenberg decomposition before, then I can use QR-algorhtm. But I missing the imaginary eigenvalues. Can only get real ones. Hmmm...how important are imaginary eigenvalues?

Comment: Does the code support imaginary for the numerical calculations? Often, to get imaginary, you have to use imaginary. For example, Newton's Method will not go from real to imaginary numbers for roots, you must provide an imaginary starting point. Might something like this be causing your issue?

Comment: @Moo This works! Look at function Eigen. https://github.com/daviddmc/numerical-analysis-toolbox/tree/master/eigen

Comment: @Moo First compute the Hessenberg decomposition H = Q’*A*Q using Householder transformations. Then use QR iteration with francis double shift algoritm. Then we have found imaginary and real eigenvalues.

Comment: Excellent, glad to hear you figured it out!